# SQL composite primary key without ordering (pair of integers in either order must be unique)

Tags: mysql, sql, union, composite-primary-key

I have a MySQL table for Users with the primary key _id, and I want to represent friendships (visibility on friends lists of other users) as a table with pairs of userId foreign keys.  I'm thinking something like:

```
CREATE TABLE UserFriendships (
  userIdA INT NOT NULL,
  userIdB INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userIdA, userIdB),
  FOREIGN KEY (userIdA) REFERENCES Users(_id)
  FOREIGN KEY (userIdB) REFERENCES Users(_id)
)
```

It's my understanding that this will allow both `(userIdA = 2, userIdB = 7)` and `(userIdA = 7, userIdB = 2)` to be inserted as distinct rows.  I want one row per friendship, that is to say one row per pair of userIds.

Does anyone know how I could improve this?  Even if the above constraint is met, to get a list of all the friends of user foo I have to do a union, something like: `SELECT userIdB AS friendUserId WHERE userIdA = foo UNION SELECT userIdA WHERE userIdB = foo`.  Is this the best way to accomplish that query, or should I think about changing my schema?

Comment: how do you deal with reciprocation?

Comment: Would be quite easy with any other DBMS, but with MySQL I can only think of a trigger solution to prevent this.

Comment: @Strawberry I hadn't thought of that, but I may include a seperate table of FriendRequests which, once reciprocated, result in an insert into UserFriendships.  Although they would contain the same data, so that seems redundant doesn't it...

Comment: @Strawberry I could also just add two more fields to UserFriendships, confirmedByUserA and confirmedByUserB.  Sender of the friend request gets their confirmation flag set, and whichever one isn't set is the recipient.

Comment: OK. Good that you're thinking about that. Next question  "I want one row per friendship, that is to say one row per pair of userIds." Why? Why not two? That way I can 'unfriend' you (i.e. prohibit you from seeing my profile/updates) without you automatically 'unfriending' me.

Comment: Oh interesting... I hadn't thought of that, I was thinking of friends as an undirected graph rather than a directed one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT` to enfore a business rule:

- `userIdA` is always the user with the lower ID and `userIdB` always the user with the higher ID

This way both combinations (A,B) and (B,A) result in the same column order with the same primary key.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER enforce_friendship_id_order BEFORE INSERT ON UserFriendships
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @lowerId := IF(NEW.userIdA < NEW.userIdB, NEW.userIdA, NEW.userIdB);
    SET @higherId := IF(NEW.userIdA > NEW.userIdB, NEW.userIdA, NEW.userIdB);
    SET NEW.userIdA = @lowerId;
    SET NEW.userIdB = @higherId;
  END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yikes.  Upvote for a working solution, but I think I'd rather leave the rule unenforced and risk duplicates than mess with triggers.  I suppose this is the kind of thing they're for, but it just doesn't feel clean, you know?

Comment: well, yes this is one of the use cases triggers are for. i don't see how a change in your table schema could help you, that's why i posted this answer. you may enfore the same business rule in your application code, but i think it belongs to the database. MySQL isn't a real help here.

Comment: @MikeTurley is "messing" with triggers so bad, really?

Comment: Only because I'm not too experienced with advanced MySQL.  I should just learn more and use them. :)